# FFMPEG create corrupted MP4 format and not play in Browser

Tags: jquery, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

I've installed `FFMPEG 2.7.2` in `CentOS 7` and its working fine with the conversion of **MP4, FLV and WEBM** from any Video, but the issue is with **MP4** extension. When I play converted **WEBM video** using **HTML5**'s `<video></video>` tag its playing but MP4 not (In FireFox and Chrome's default player says that video file is corrupted).

Below command is for MP4 :

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -vcodec mpeg4 -r 30 -b:v 2000000 -acodec limp3lame -ab 126000 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -s 1280x720 output.mp4 -y 2> /dev/null &
```

Can anyone tell me that where I'm doing mistake in above command, so I can change the command and convert valid MP4 video which plays into Web Browser supported format.

Answer (score 1):

`-vcodec mpeg4` is used to encode Xvid.  You need to use `-vcodec libx264` instead in order to encode H.264.